# Matlab 3D probabilty histogram by 2D array

Tags: matlab, histogram, matlab-figure

I have 2D data structed by 64X100000 size. 64(rows) represent "phase (-31:1:32)" and 100000 (column) represent "voltage" about the range of (-0.4 ~ 0.4).

I want to watch a probabilty based histogram (pdf) of this data in 64 time instances.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNHNd.png)<----- Like this pic.

How can I make a 3D plot that shows the changes of voltage histogram through 64 phases?